# Синхронизация процесса тестирования на 2х клиентах

Tags: c#, автоматизация, uiautomation, mstest

Есть задача - автоматизировать тест, в котором участвуют 2 копии приложения (2 клиента) одновременно.

Суть в том, что, пока 1-ый клиент работает с данными, эти данные должны быть недоступны для 2-го клиента. Ну и как только 1-ый клиент закончил работать с данными и сохранил результат, объект становится доступным для 2-го клиента.

Приложение - WPF клиент на windows. Тесты пишутся на C#, MS UI Automation, MSTest, SpecFlow.

Существует ли возможность параллельного выполнения таких тестов? Или же это не является "хорошей практикой" и лучше заменить 1-го клиента запросами к сервису?

*Дополнение*: приложение запускается только в 1 экземпляре.

Answer (score 2):

Для более конкретного совета нужны подробности вашей архетиктуры, но я бы попробовал опуститься на уровень ниже, к юнит-тестам.

Предположу, что у вас есть вполне конкретный класс Client для представления пользователя, и есть какой-то метод проверки "заняты" конкретные данные в данные момент, или нет (с возможностью его подменить).

Далее псевдокод:

```
[ExpectedException(DataBlockedException)]
public ClientBlockingTest()
{
    var client = new Client(user, password);
    var someData = new MockedData(block: true);

    client.DoSomething(someData);
}

public ClientBlockingTest()
{
    var client = new Client(user, password);
    var someData = new MockedData(block: false);

    var result = client.DoSomething(someData);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Comment: Maronus, юнит тесты пишутся отдельно. У меня задача автоматизировать мануальные регрессионные тесты WPF клиента.
Вопрос, собственно в том, можно ли синхронизировать как-либо исполнение теста на 2х машинах? (клиент на 1 машине запускается только 1). Причем, чтобы каждый "клиент" выполнял свою часть флоу.
Что касается архитектуры - в данном случае, мне кажется, не актуально...

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе описано, что вы ***делаете***, но ничего не сказано, что вы ***хотите сделать***.

Речь идёт о юнит-тестировании или интеграционном? Мне нравится высказанная ранее мысль о том, что нужно начинать с юнит-тестирования, поставил плюс.

Смотрите.

У вас есть в солюшене проект(ы), содержащий серверную часть и на неё написаны отдельные юнит тесты на проверу бизнес-логики.

У вас в этом же солюшене также есть проект(ы), содержащие клиента и на неё должны быть написаны свои тесты. При этом вы запускаете для теста настоящий сервер и вот это я считаю проблемой: возможно, вы не знаете, что такое mock в тестировании. Я предлагаю вам в тесте запускать клиента не к реальному серверу, а к заглушке с демо-данными.

Проблема залочки данных отпадает при этом сама собой, как и проблема распараллеливания тестов.

Comment: A K, про мокинг знаю, но я не пишу юнит-тесты. У меня задача интеграционного тестирования. UI WPF клиента...
Ниже я дополнил описание (что именно необходимо сделать). Но я все больше склоняюсь к мысли, что 1й клиент должен быть заменен API запросами...